# Passing function as an argument without wrapper does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Very strange situation. I want to pass function CKEDITOR.instances.Content.insertText (expecting string as input) as an argument to my JS function, which calls it with its own string. If I pass CKEDITOR.instances.Content.insertText directly, it does not work and results in

Uncaught TypeError: this.fire is not a function(…)

but when I use wrapper (called w below) it works just fine. The type of argument passed in (insertText) is reported as function, so why doesnt it work? It must be some kind of special function of which I am not aware of. Any ideas? Since I have a workaround I am interested in why it doesnt work, not how to fix it.

```
        var f = function(func,arg)
        {
            func(arg);
        }

        var w = function (arg) // Wrapper around insertText.
        {
            CKEDITOR.instances.Content.insertText(arg);
        }

        var myFunc = function(arg) // Simulating insertText.
        {
            alert(arg);
        }

        CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function() {
            f(myFunc,'test'); // works, alerts correctly
            f(w, 'does work'); // works, appends text to CKEditor window
            f(CKEDITOR.instances.Content.insertText, 'does not work'); // error, while the argument is confirmed as function!
        });
```

Comment: When you pass the function _by itself_ it loses the context it has. If you call `CKEDITOR.instances.Content.insertText()` it _will_ have the context then. What you can do is use `.bind` to set it - `CKEDITOR.instances.Content.insertText.bind(CKEDITOR.instances.Content)` and then pass that to `f`. Gets a bit verbose, though but can be shortened.

Comment: didnt know that, thanks!